# If $f\,:\,A\to A$ is surjective and not injective then what can I say about $A$'s size?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Studying for my finals in Logic. Although the question is about Set Theory. In one of the previous exams, there was the following statement:

> If $f\,:\,A\to A$ is injective and not surjective then the size of $A$ is infinite.

It's been a while sense I last had to deal with Set Theory. Then I saw this post [If $f:A\rightarrow A$ is injective but not surjective then $A$ is infinite.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2892444/if-fa-rightarrow-a-is-injective-but-not-surjective-then-a-is-infinite) which cleared some things. But I could not find explanations of the following questions:

1. If $f\,:\,A\to A$ is surjective and not injective then what can I say about $A$'s size? is it finite?
2. If $f\,:\,A\to A$ is surjective and injective then what can I say about $A$'s size? is it infinite? I guess it's more general case the the explained one so $A$ has to be infinite. Is it true?

Comment: What is "surjective and surjective"?

Comment: If $A$ is finite, then a function $f : A \to A$ is injective iff it is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

1. If $f: A \rightarrow A$ is surjective and not injective then $A$ must be infinite. To see this let take for example the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}$. If you construct $f$ in such a way that it assigns even two (or more) elements to one element there is no way to make it surjective. It can be shown more formally using induction, I think.
   But if $A$ is infinite then it is possible to construct $f$ so that it would be surjective and not injective. Simple example: let us consider $A = N_+$. Then let's define $f$ in this way:
   $f(1) = 1$
   $f(2) = 1$
   $f(3) = 2$
   $f(4) = 3$
   $f(5) = 4$
   $.....$
2. Nothing can be said from the fact that $f: A \rightarrow A$ is surjective and injective. For identity is always surjective and injective and you can define identity on any set.

Answer (score 0):

If $f: A \to A$ is surjective and not injective then $A$ must be infinite. This is a direct consequence of the 'pigeonhole principle', which says that if $A$ and $B$ are two finite sets with the same number of elements and $f:A \to B$, then $f$ is an injection $\iff$ $f$ is a surjection. Thus, if you suppose that $A$ is finite, you get an immediate contradiction through the existence of this function $f$.

As for your second question if $f$ is both surjective and injective you can tell nothing about the cardinality of $A$. For any set $A$ there is such a function (the identity for instance), and this holds irrespective of the cardinality of $A$.