# Injections, Surjections and proper subset

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I am having trouble with the following proof, It feels intuitive but I am having trouble bringing together a formal proof. Can someone just give me an outline of how they would go about writing a proof.

- Every injective function X -> X is surjective.
- For every proper subset Y of X there is no surjection Y -> X.

Prove that the two conditions above are equivalent.

Comment: How about the map $n \rightarrow n + 1$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @badjohn the set of natural numbers is not a counter-example, since it fails both conditions, for the first take the function $n \mapsto 2n$, for the second, just pick $Y$ to be any non finite subset of $\mathbb N$.

Comment: @TomásPacheco It was intended as a counterexample to the first not the second.  What have I missed?

Comment: @badjohn Hello, unless I am mistaken the goal is to prove that for any set $X$, these two conditions are equivalent, in the sense that if the space satisfies one of the conditions, then satisfies the other. On the other hand, if it doesn't satisfy one of them, it satisfies neither.

Comment: Try proving (at least that the first condition implies the second) by contraposition. By this I mean instead of proving $(1) \implies (2)$, prove $not (1) \implies not (2)$, note that these logicals statements are the same.

Comment: @TomásPacheco I tried doing exactly that, but I ended up getting nowhere. I just dont know how to structure it, I just end up with something that almost sounds like I am repeating the question just in a different way.

Comment: @TomásPacheco Yes, I have misread the task.

Comment: Also relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2892444

Answer (score 0):

The proof below uses the axiom of choice. Could someone share a solution without using choice, or explain why choice is necessary?

---

Let $Y \subset X$ be a proper subset of $X$, and suppose there exists some surjection $f \colon Y \to X$. Then, by the axiom of choice, there exists an injection $g \colon X \to Y$. Let $\iota \colon Y \to X$ be the inclusion of $Y$ into $X$, that is, $\iota(y) = y$ for all $y\in Y$. Then we have an injection $\iota \circ g \colon X \to X$ which is not surjective.

For the converse, suppose there exists an injection $f \colon X \to X$ which is not surjective. Let $Y = f(X)$ be the image of $X$ under $f$, noting that $Y$ is a proper subset of $X$. Then $f$ is bijective as a function from $X$ to $Y$. So $f^{-1}$ is a bijection, and hence a surjection, from $Y$ to $X$.

Comment: The axiom of choice is necessary. It is consistent that there is an infinite set $X$ such that every injective $f\colon X\to X$ is surjective, but there is some $Y\subsetneq X$ such that $Y$ maps onto $X$.

Comment: Thank you, @AsafKaragila

Answer (score 0):

Proving $(1) \implies (2)$:

The negation of statement $(2)$ reads:

"There exists a proper subset $Y \subset X$ and a function $f:Y \rightarrow X$ that is surjective.

We shall assume this and we want to prove the negation of statement (1):

"There exists a function $g:X \rightarrow X$ which is injective but not surjective."

Lets start, assume there is $f$ as above and assume further that $f$ is injective. Then the inverse of $f$
$$
f^{-1}:X \rightarrow Y \subset X,
$$
is injective but not surjective because $Y$ is a proper subset.

Problem now is if $f$ is not injective. No worries, we can turn it into an injective function, without ruining surjectivity. Ok there is actual a small worry here, since I think this requires the axiom of choice:

For all $x \in X$, consider the subset $I_x = \{ z \in X: f(z) = f(x) \}$ and for every of these sets, we pick an element $z_{I_x}$ and define $Z = \{z_{I_x}: x \in X\}$, now that we have this set the restriction $f|_Z$ is injective and the inverse of it satisfies what we want, as it was done above

Answer (score 0):

For the proof $(1) \implies (2)$, you need axiom of choice, as the others have already showed extensively. The other direction does not, and has a quite simple proof.

---

Proving $(2) \implies (1)$ by means of contrapositive:

Assume (1) does not hold. Then we find a function $f: X \to X$ that is injective but not surjective. Let $Y = f(X)$, i.e. $Y$ is the range of $f$. Because $f$ is not surjective, $Y$ is a proper subset of $X$, or $Y \subset X$.

Then, by restricting $f$ to its image, we get that $f: X \to Y$ is both injective and surjective, so it has an inverse, $g: Y \to X$. An inverse of a bijection is bijective, so $g$ is in particular surjective. Hence we have shown $(2)$ does not hold, proving this arrow.